# Cucumber-jvm Hooks when Scenario is passed or failed

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, jbehave

In **Jbehave** we can execute method upon outcome of scenario success/failure. One of the below mentioned methods will execute after failure and success.

```
@AfterScenario(uponOutcome=AfterScenario.Outcome.SUCCESS)
public void afterSuccessfulScenario() {
// Some code to execute...
}

@AfterScenario(uponOutcome=AfterScenario.Outcome.FAILURE)
public void afterFailedScenario() {
// Some code to execute...
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in **Cucumber-jvm**. The scenario Hooks `@Before` and `@After` will execute after each scenario. But I want to execute some code  for each failure scenario.

I am not sure how to implement it in cucumber-jvm. Any clue?

Comment: @vaibhavcool20
If you want to get the stacktrace, see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52117066/10299604

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve it using `cucumber-jvm hooks`. 
If a hook receive a [`Scenario`](http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/Scenario.html) as a parameter, you can know if it has failed or not.

Example:

```
@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
  if (scenario.isFailed()) {
     // Some code to execute...
  }
  if(scenario.isPassed()) {
     // Some code to execute...
  }
}
```

Note the import of `@After`:

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can i get stack trace in @After?

Comment: @vaibhavcool20 Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542557/how-to-get-the-exception-that-was-thrown-when-a-cucumber-test-failed-in-java/52117066#52117066). I think it solves what you want to achieve