# How to get information about exception thrown in AfterScenario hook in Gauge framework?

Tags: java, getgauge

I'm using Gauge framework with Java as part of the automation suite. We get the information whether a scenario is failing or not from the *isFailing*  flag in *executionContext.getCurrentScenario()*.
**But can we get the reason it is failing - if assertion failed or some exception occurred, etc. - in AfterScenario?**

There is a *executionContext.getCurrentStep().getErrorMessage()* and *executionContext.getCurrentStep().getStackTrace()* but they don't seem to give the required failed information. Is there any way we can do it?

Came across a similar question in cucumber framework here: [How to get the exception that was thrown when a Cucumber test failed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542557/how-to-get-the-exception-that-was-thrown-when-a-cucumber-test-failed-in-java) Can something similar be applied?